# Query value for list of Ids from memcache

Tags: caching, memcached

I was going through the memcache documentation and i do see `get` method which can be use to fetch value of a given key.

Is there a way to fetch values for a given set of keys in a single round trip to memcache server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: **Yes, there is. Not as directly support as Redis, but yes.**
Protocol-level support you may want to know is `quiet mode`, which you can refer [here](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/BinaryProtocolRevamped#get-get-quietly-get-key-get-key-quietly). And I quote as below :

> Clients should implement multi-get (still important for reducing network roundtrips!) as n pipelined requests, the first n-1 being getq/getkq, the last being a regular get/getk.

According to `SpyMemcached`, you can use `getBulk`. The implementation of `getBulk` is fire n `getq` operations, and followed by one `noop` operation. The following is the code snippet :

```
// set up the initial header stuff
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
for (Map.Entry<Integer, byte[]> me : bkeys.entrySet()) {
  final byte[] keyBytes = me.getValue();
  final String key = keys.get(me.getKey());

  // Custom header
  bb.put(REQ_MAGIC);
  bb.put(CMD_GETQ);
  bb.putShort((short) keyBytes.length);
  bb.put((byte) 0); // extralen
  bb.put((byte) 0); // data type
  bb.putShort(vbmap.get(key).shortValue()); // vbucket
  bb.putInt(keyBytes.length);
  bb.putInt(me.getKey());
  bb.putLong(0); // cas
  // the actual key
  bb.put(keyBytes);
}
// Add the noop
bb.put(REQ_MAGIC);
bb.put((byte) NoopOperationImpl.CMD);
bb.putShort((short) 0);
bb.put((byte) 0); // extralen
bb.put((byte) 0); // data type
bb.putShort((short) 0); // reserved
bb.putInt(0);
bb.putInt(terminalOpaque);
bb.putLong(0); // cas

bb.flip();
setBuffer(bb);
```

Nothing to do with `threadpool`, let's say that, we send data of n memcached packages in one network package and get all the data in one response. I skip the process to deal with multi node as you may not care.

Comment: wow.. i have completed `how to run memcache guide` few days back. So can you please explain in a byte more detail as your answer is too cryptic for me to understand.... from you quote does it mean the user of memcache should implement multiget by sending multiple get request using threadpool?

Comment: @user2410148 updated the answer and hope that I have made myself a little bit clearer.